# Netgear router access via http

Tags: php, android, http, authentication, basic-authentication

I am trying to access my Netgear R8000 router web interface via http using php from an android device but it always returns a 401 page. I have set up the headers to use Basic Authentication as well.

My goal is to access the pull the amount of data transferred (data usage) from the Netgear R8000 router configuration web interface. I am making a call from a php page hosted on an android device, but I always get a 401 response even after setting the headers for Basic Authentication.

This is what I have currently:

```
<?php
    $login = 'admin';
    $password = 'password';
    $url = 'http://192.168.1.1/traffic_meter.htm';

    $process = curl_init($host);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    curl_close($process);

    echo $return;
?>
```

I have also tried to specify the Authorization header manually, but the results were the same. However, if I make the same call using PostMan (on a PC on the same network), it works as expected.

I have ensured that the android device has connectivity to the router using the same IP address.

Can someone help me understand why this isn't working?